# Highcharts set global timezone for all charts

Tags: highcharts, timezone

I'm trying to set my timezone for all charts on my webpage to America/New_York.
I tried many things, using timezoneoffset, timezone with moment.js.
Seems like impossible for me for some reason.
Can someone please help me to set the timezone to the timezone I want, instead of using the client's timezone.
Thank you.

Comment: check this https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezone from highcharts docs

Comment: Tried that one, not working.. gives me a error

Comment: add code how you used highcharts